# Is T Self Adjoint?Is T Bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, inner-products

> Let $T:\ell^2\rightarrow \ell^2$ be defined by
> $T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...)\rightarrow
>  (0,0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...)$.Is $T$ Self Adjoint?Is $T$
> Bounded?

*$T$ is Self-Adjoint*

$\langle T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...),(\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_4,...)\rangle$

=$\langle(0,0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...),(\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_4,...)\rangle$

Now,

$\langle T^*(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...),(\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_4,...)\rangle$

=$\langle (\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...),T(\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_4,...)\rangle$

=$\langle(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...),(0,0,\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_4,...)\rangle$

Since,$\langle(0,0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...),(\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_4,...)\rangle\neq \langle(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,...),(0,0,\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_4,...)\rangle$

So,$T\neq T^* \implies T$ is not Self Adjoint.

Please Check the above proof whether it is correct or not?

I'm not getting how to show that $T$ is bounded...I've given a lots of time in proving the boundedness...If possible,please show how $T$ is bounded?

Comment: Calculate $\|T\xi\|$ and compare with $\|\xi\|.$

Comment: As for the auto-adjoint part, your proof is correct, though to be perfectly rigorous you'd want to exhibit a concrete example as to why there's not equality.

Comment: For boundedness, I would suggest to find a reason that justifies $\| Tx \|_2 = \| x\|_2, \, \forall x \in \ell^2.$ Indeed, this is just some complement on Ryszard's comment.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc:$\|T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)\|=\|(0,0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)\|=\sum\vert\xi_i\vert^2<\infty$,Also $\|(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)\|=\sum\vert\xi_i\vert^2<\infty$ this implies  $\|T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)\|=\|(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)\|$...Correct?

Comment: @BrunoB:$\langle T(1,1/4,1/9,1/16,1/25,...),(1,1/16,1/81,1/256,...)\rangle$

=$\langle(0,0,1,1/4,1/9,1/16,1/25,...),(1,1/16,1/81,1/256,...)\rangle=1/81+1/1024+...$


Now,

$\langle T^*(1,1/4,1/9,1/16,1/25,...),(1,1/16,1/81,1/256,...)\rangle$

=$\langle (1,1/4,1/9,1/16,1/25,...),T(1,1/16,1/81,1/256,...)\rangle$

=$\langle(1,1/4,1/9,1/16,1/25,...),(0,0,1,1/16,1/81,1/256,...)\rangle=1/9+1/1296+...$

Since,$1/81+1/1024+...\neq 1/9+1/1296+...$

So,$T\neq T^* \implies T$ is not Self Adjoint.

Comment: @BrunoB:is the above example correct?

Comment: You would need to show that the sums are not equal. Luckily here the $1/9$ is big enough that there could be a way to salvage this maybe, but you should try looking for simpler counterexamples. Don't forget that sequences with a finite number of nonzero terms are pretty much always an option for simple sequences to test things like this.

Comment: Correct. The operator $T$ is thus an isometry. Concerning self-adjointness either you calculate $T^*$ explicitly or observe that $\langle Te_1,e_3\rangle =1$ and $\langle  e_1,Te_3\rangle=0$ where $e_n$ denotes the standard basis in $\ell^2.$